# Hiding methods from the GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am implementing the observer pattern in java to separate my model classes from the GUI.
The problem is that, every time the update-method is called, the model-instance is given as a parameter. That means, the GUI can call methods on the model-objects which should not be called from the GUI.
How to avoid that the GUI can manipulate the model objects?

Comment: You can use Java packages to give the controller(s) access to methods that the GUI doesn't have access to.  Or you can rely on the honor system.

Comment: if you decide to use a wrapper object, some ides can help you create it. For example, in eclipse `source > create delegate methods` will copy all the methods, forwarding the calls to an inner composed object. then you just delete the others you dont want to expose.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you need to introduce another layer that will take a model object and convert it into DTO and return to GUI and vice versa. Kind of Data access design pattern used in many projects.

For more information [visit this link](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Hope this gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Interface for the model class that only defines the methods that the GUI can call (i.e. a subset of the methods currently implemented by the model class that should only be seen by the GUI)
- Have the model class implement this new Interface, which should be trivial since the methods are already implemented there.
- In the methods where the model is passed, change the parameter type from the class of your model to the new interface that the model now implements